# Does ffmpeg support dynamically reconfigure filter graph now?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg C API to develop some video mix program, and I use ffmpeg `scale`, `crop` and `overlay` filter to implement this. My program works well when the input video's resolution keep unchanged. But my input video stream does change resolution frequently. Currently I handle the resolution change by destroying the filter graph and then rebuilding it, but I don't think frequently destroying and rebuilding filter graph is a good idea because it takes time to do this process.

So I wonder if there is any already implemented feature in ffmpeg that can dynamically reconfigure video resolution of the filter graph.

I have done some google search and find some discussion on this feature. Here is the related disscution:
https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2012-October/002920.html
http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2012-October/133012.html

But I can't find out any conclusion of this feature.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: You don't need to reconfigure filtergraph. Just make sure the initial filter is scale or null and buffersrc won't complain.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks a lot! I tried to set scale as the first filter, here is the filter chain: `[in]scale=100:100:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase:eval=frame,crop=100:100:(iw-ow)/2:(ih-oh)/2[out];`. Yeah, the `scale` filter does support variable input resolution, this is good. But when `scale` input is variable, `scale` output is also variable, which becomes the input of `crop` filter. But it seems `crop` does not support variable input resolution. And I checked ffmpeg source code, `crop` does not evaluate `iw` at each input frame. So it goes back to the original question. :(

Comment: So I wonder if there is a `crop_beta` filter that support variable input resolution. Or is there a framework level solution instead of filter level in ffmpeg that can deal with this case?

Comment: crop works with variable resolution input, due to lack of checks rather than formal accommodation; just make sure the input is always larger than crop out w / h to avoid unexpected results.

Comment: @Gyan This can be promised by `scale=force_original_aspect_ratio=increase`. I wonder if the cropped video is still centered when `crop` input resolution changed? It seems `iw` is not evaluated every frame in `x` expression `(iw-ow)/2` of `crop` filter.

Comment: It seems `VAR_IN_W` is only evaluated in [config_input](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/9fbdd5454bba660a2ec3aa4da31183b2f7fd3bc8/libavfilter/vf_crop.c#L139).

Comment: Yes, variable-referenced co-ordinates will be wrong. I'll add dynamic support when I have time ... say, a few weeks.

Comment: OK, thx. Maybe I will try to fix by myself. I need this feature now.

Comment: In your own tree, sure. Expect review to take time if you want to add it upstream.